# Обработка нажатия клавиш в фоновом режиме. Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Знаю, что в фоновом режиме можно отловить нажатия клавиш при помощи pyHook, но насколько мне известно, последняя версия pyHook работает в python 2.7. Возможно ли реализовать это в python 3.7? Если да, то какие модули для этого подойдут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard):

```
# pip install keyboard
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(e, e.event_type, e.name)

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

---

Еще пример:

```
# pip install keyboard
import keyboard

def foo():
    print('World')

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', lambda: print('Hello'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 2', foo)

keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} released')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]