# Как мне вывести нажатия клавиатуры в текстовый файл?

Tags: python, клавиатура

```
import keyboard
import os

def Letter(e):
    print(e, e.event_type, e.name, e.time)
keyboard.hook(Letter)
```

Comment: Как записывать я знаю, Мне нужно чтобы НАЖАТИЯ в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
FILENAME = 'key_records.txt'
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    global FILENAME
    f = open(FILENAME, 'a')
    f.write(f"Была {'нажата' if e.event_type == 'down' else 'отпущена'} кнопка {e.name}\n")
    f.close()

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Результат работы в файле `key_records.txt`:

```
Была отпущена кнопка w
Была нажата кнопка d
Была нажата кнопка a
Была отпущена кнопка d
Была нажата кнопка s
Была отпущена кнопка a
Была отпущена кнопка s
Была нажата кнопка a
Была нажата кнопка f
Была отпущена кнопка f
Была нажата кнопка w
Была отпущена кнопка a
Была нажата кнопка a
Была отпущена кнопка w
Была нажата кнопка d
Была отпущена кнопка a
Была отпущена кнопка d
```

Ответ на вопрос об обработке событий клавиатуры есть в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916875/) теме.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: @Ivandatlov если ответ вам помог, вы можете поставить возле него галочку, чтобы отметить его, как правильный

Answer (score -2):

Простой пример с записью файла:

```
# Создаёт новый файл с названием test.txt и открывает его на запись
# про то, что на запись говорит 2 аргумент функции (w - write)
f = open('test.txt', 'w')

# Записывает что-то в этот файл
f.write('Stackoverflow')

# закрывает файл и сохраняет его
f.close
```