# Посоветуйте модуль для реагирования на нажатие клавиш

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, клавиатура, модули

посоветуйте **модуль** для *реагирования на нажатие клавиш*. Я работал с модулем от **tkinter (Canvas)**:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window)
c.pack()
def a():
    key = event.keysym
    if key == 'w':
        КАКОЙ-ТО КОД
c.bind_all("<KeyPress>", a)
window.mainloop()
```

Но он не может реагировать на нажатие нескольких клавиш **одновременно**, посоветуйте модуль, который может *реагировать на нажатие нескольких клавиш одновременно*, спасибо.

Comment: Настолько, что ответ нужен сегодня

Comment: Можно и через tkinter сделать, только нужно привязываться к событиям `<KeyPress>` (событие нажатия на кнопку) и `<KeyRelease>` (событие отпускания кнопки). Если для двух (и более) кнопок было нажатие, но не было отпускания, значит они в данный момент нажаты одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно реагировать на нажатия кнопок клавиатуры, вам может подойти модуль `keyboard`
Устанавливается через pip (`pip install keyboard`)

Примеры работы модуля: [Пример 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117072/), [Пример 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916875/)